# change system table information (newsletter_subscriber)

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am developing website in Magento in which i have used default newsletter feature provided by Magento.

But i want to customize default feature provided by Magento.

**customizations i want to do**

- Change the default table name to "emails"
- add fields to the table(found way to do this, but don't know if it's possible after changing table name)

Is this possible to do this customizations?
If it's possible, then how i can do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the default new letter email structure can be done with changing the format of newsletter in  your themes locale folder or creating a new newsletter template in admin panel and assigning it throught the configuration menu.

Suppose you want to change the template of unsubscribe of newsletter, In admin panel, we have the option of creating a newsletter template by system/transaction emails.  Here you can create a new template. After creating the template as required, In system/configuration, customers/newsletters, Here if we select the tetbox of unsubscription email sender dropdown, You can see your newly created newsletter template. Then save page. I hope it helps u.

Comment: I didn't get it. can u be more specific ?

Comment: I don't want to create new template i jst want to rename the default table and add fields to that table.